# jquery will not work for me!

Tags: jquery

It's weird! I was working on my CSS and jquery just stopped working! checked in firefox/chrome and the jquery just stopped working!  I have no idea what happen.

I have 2 functions going on. First part animates the header image and the second part generates random numbers when it is click. I pasted my whole code at pastebin.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Hello </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- #header Image -->
  <img id="header" src="images/header.png" width="424" height="63" alt="Header">
  <!-- /#header Image -->
  <div id="main-wrapper">
    <h1> Your points will be genarated below </h1>

    <form>
      <input id="points" type="text"/>
      <input type="button" id="generate" value="Generate Points!" />
    </form>

  </div><!-- /#main-wrapper -->
  <!-- Generate -->
  <script src="js/gen.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>

$(document).ready(function(){
      // Makes the image go under the div wrapper.
     $('img#header').css({'position' : 'relative', 'top' : '17px', 'z-index' : '50' })
    //create the animation
     $('img#header').hover(function()
  {
    $(this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({"top": "-3px" }, "slow");
      }, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"top": "17px"}, "slow");
  });



  // Generate Numbers 
    $("#generate").click(function(){
      var code = "";
      var alphabet = new Array('A', 'B', 'C', 
               'D', 'E', 'F', 
               'G', 'H', 'I', 
               'J', 'K', 'L', 
                 'M', 'N', 'O', 
                 'P', 'Q', 'R', 
               'S', 'T', 'U', 
               'U', 'V', 'W', 
                 'X', 'Y', 'Z');
        var count = 5 * 4;
        for (var i=0; i<count; i++){
          var number = false;
          var type = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
          if (type == 0) number = true; else number = false;
            var output;
            if (number){
              code += String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
          }
            else
          {
            var ranChar = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)
            code += alphabet[ranChar];
          }
          if (((i+1) % 5 == 0) && i != count-1) code += "-";
        }
          $("#points").val(code);
      });
    });


body { background: #0d0d0d url(../images/body-bg.jpg) repeat; width: 500px; margin: 154px auto; } 
img#header { padding: 0 41px; }

div#main-wrapper { background: #dfdfdf; border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; position: relative; z-index: 1000; padding:                       44px  64px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;  }

div#main-wrapper h1 { color: #0d0d0d; font: italic bold 1.2em Georgia, Arial, Serif; text-align: center; text-shadow: -1px 1px 0 #fff; margin-bottom: 38px; }

/* Form Generator */
form {}
form input[type="text"]#points { background: #d6d6d6; border: 1px #909090 solid; display: block; font: bold 1.3em Arial, Serif; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px;  }
form input[type="button"]#generate { background: #2d69bd; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 71%, from(#3171CA), to(#15396F)); background: -moz-linear-gradient(21% 74% 90deg,#15396F, #3171CA); border: 1px #5b93d1 solid; border-radius: 16px; -webkit-border-radius: 16px; -moz-border-radius: 16px; padding: 10px; }
```

The css and jquery was working, then for some reason it stopped working.

Comment: missing semicolon on line `35` ?

Comment: This isn't a real question. You need to distill what you were doing down a little further to give people a better understanding of what might be causing the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know. Everything was working and then it just stopped.

Comment: @ jAndy the semicolon is there just on a new line.

Comment: Any errors in the JS Console of your browser?

Comment: js/jquery.js:92Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input



js/gen.js:1Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Error console, html valid, cache, jslint,...

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Guys, I fixed it, I just used google hosted cdn for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say your jQuery was working fine until you starting working on your CSS. Could it be because you're not closing your CSS includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
```

Should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" />
```

Comment: Nope, tags doesn't need to be closed, I tried though and still didn't work.

Comment: @kawohi-dev: They **should** be closed... Not closing them is bad practice in HTML5, and illegal (bad syntax) in XHTML.

Comment: Oh.... well there closed and still didn't work.. I thought it wasn't really needed in HTML5.

Comment: And the HTML still validates.

Comment: @kawohi-dev - I'm confused - you marked this as an answer, but you said this didn't solve your problem. Then, you posted saying that you solved the problem but didn't give an explanation. Please choose one or the other and give an explanation of the solution (if this isn't it) so that others can benefit from the solution.

Comment: @Jason - I actually tested my above answer and managed to replicate the issue. I.e. not closing the tag caused my JS files underneath to stop working. But like you, I too would like to know whether there's another reason; it seems strange for the OP to say this didn't work and mark is as correct. I'd rather know the answer and not have the accept.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - Yeah. I wasn't trying to have the OP remove the answer from you - I just couldn't figure out whether this was the real solution or not and was hoping for further clarification.

Comment: @Andrew Moore: I haven't seen anything which suggests that not closing link tags is bad practice in HTML5 (assuming we're not talking about the XML serialisation). Do you have a reference?